# How can I print a attribute on phtml?

Tags: magento2, product, blocks

I want show relation information from the products under the descriptions, this information shouldn't be inside a tab but as if it were a dynamic block, for example, each product will have a different author. And I want to show this author. How should do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if($product->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute') !== null) {
    $customAttribute = $product->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute')->getValue();
    echo $customAttribute;
}
```

Comment: It dont work for me, I put this code under my tabs and when i update the magento my tabs dissapear and dont show nothing

Comment: What is the name of your product object ?

Comment: it isn't on my file where im working, the object product doesnt exist in my current file

Comment: ahuuum, in this case you have to do product collection in block module, then you get that collection exemple : `public function getCustomProdCollection()` in your phtml in the same module like this `$block->getCustomprodCollection()` and now you do some foreach on it then you will ba able to get your attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
if($author = $_product->getAuthor()){
    echo $author;
}
```

Here attribute code is **author** if its **product_author** then it will **getProductAuthor()**

Comment: It dont work for me, I put this code under my tabs and when i update the magento my tabs dissapear and dont show nothing

Comment: Where did you add this code? Can you please update your code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do code like this.

```
<?php 
    $OM = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product= $OM->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');

    if($product->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute') !== null) {
         $customAttribute = $product->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute')->getValue();
         echo $customAttribute;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Where do I have to put that? On view or controller?

Comment: you need to add this on view.